autotest Android (Appium/UiAutomator2/selenium) - The Appium server takes a long time to process the request
I have autotests for Android phone version 13, I run tests, I see a request to the device in the logs, but the device does not respond for a long time (this happens in different parts of the code, each time in a new place)
before the phone was on version 11, there were no such problems
help me figure out the situation
appium java version 7.6.0 ,
appium version 1.22.3 ,
api version 33
I can't show the screenshots because of the security policy
at the time of the error in the logs, I see: a search request / click on an element and then a long pause (150-200 seconds), then a 200 or 404 response comes (depending on the presence of the element on the device)
, then the test can be performed successfully and hang again at some random moment
updated Android programs (api version)
